# I would like to create a query where I select name from table which don't contain characters that are z,n,m?

Tags: mysql, database

SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE NOT LIKE('%Z%' AND '%M%' AND '%N%');

Comment: so, what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use three `not like` conditions:

```
where col not like '%z%' and col not like '%m%' and col not like '%n%'
```

Answer (score 0):

WHERE col_name NOT REGEXP '[zmn]'